# Confused on Regex Missing some matches and hitting others

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have a regex function that finds all matches of a word within html on a page and replaces that with a string that includes html(essentially places a span around it with a highlight CSS class).

It is working as intended but is missing most matches in some areas and I can't point out why it would miss matches in other areas considering there is no difference in the html. I will bold which word matches it would hit in a scenario and which it wouldn't I would leave italicized.

Lets say the word given that I want matched in the formula is "income"

```
<p> This is the **income**of your **income** welcome to the **income**</p>

<p> Loren ipsum loren ipsum  Loren ipsum loren ipsum  Loren ipsum loren income  Loren ipsum loren ipsum *income* Loren ipsum loren ipsum  Loren ipsum loren ipsum  Loren ipsum loren ipsum **income**. </p>
```

sometimes it will match with an instance of the word 'income' in one page refresh and others it will not. Very strange.

Here is the listed Regex that I am using below

`const regex = new RegExp('<(?!th)[^>]*>[^<]*(\\b' + wordToMatch + '\\b)', 'gi');`

Currently its doing what is intended which is

- ignoring any inline text within a th tag
- capturing only the whole word
- capturing more than one instance of the word (but missing some instances)
- capturing only text in-between tags
- case insensitive

If anyone has any theories I am open to hear them! and yes I know there are better ways than using Regex.

```js
function highlight() {

  var lastSearch = "The income";
  var inputText = $('.component.content');


  if (lastSearch) {
    lastSearch = lastSearch.split(' ');
    for (var index in lastSearch) {
      var MatchedWord = lastSearch[index];
      if (MatchedWord.length > 2 && inputText && inputText.length > 0) {
        var innerHTML = inputText[0].innerHTML;
        var doesTermExist = innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(MatchedWord.toLowerCase());
        if (doesTermExist >= 0) {
          const regex = new RegExp('<(?!th)[^>]*?>[^<]*(\\b' + MatchedWord + '\\b)', 'gi');
          $('.component.content').first().html($('.component.content').first().html().replace(regex,
            function(match, capture) {
              return match.substr(0, match.length - capture.length) + "<span class='document-highlight'>" + capture + "</span>"
            }));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', highlight);
```

```css
.document-highlight {
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../JS_Sitecore_ScratchPAge/eroc.css">
  <link/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="component title">
    <div class="component-content">
      <h1 class="field-title">Wet vs. Dry Funding States</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="component content">
    <div class="component-content">
      <div class="field-content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 container">
            <h2></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table-complex primary" style="text-align: center;">
          <thead>
            <tr class="primary-type">
              <th colspan="2">WET FUNDING STATES: Funds are sent on date of Closing or date of disbursement<br />
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="data">
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Alabama</span></td>
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Nebraska</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Arkansas</span></td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">New Hampshire</span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Colorado</span></td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">New Jersey</span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Connecticut</span></td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">New Mexico (purchases)</span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Delaware</span></td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">New York</span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">District of Columbia</span></td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">North Carolina</span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Florida</span></td>
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">North Dakota</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Georgia</span></td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Ohio</span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Illinois</span></td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Oklahoma</span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Indiana</span></td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Pennsylvania</span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Iowa</span></td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Rhode Island</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <th>income income the welcome to the jungle</th>
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Kansas</span></td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">South Carolina</span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Kentucky</span></td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">South Dakota</span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Louisiana</span></td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">The</span>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">further</span>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">th</span>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">furthe</span>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Further</span>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">the further</span>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Tennessee</span>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Tennessee</span>&nbsp;</td>

            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Maine</span>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Utah</span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Maryland</span></td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Texas</span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Massachusetts</span></td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Vermont</span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Michigan</span>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Virginia</span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Minnesota</span></td>
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">West Virginia</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Mississippi</span></td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Wisconsin</span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Missouri</span></td>
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Wyoming</span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>&nbsp;<span style="text-align: center;">Montana</span></td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>
                <p>Note that while the Freddie Mac guidance referenced below refers to the selling guide section 5307.1 in relation to securities accounts (stocks, bonds, mutual funds) and depository account (checking/savings), the Fannie Mae guidance is
                  not written in their selling guide. Only a handful of lenders have received permission to use this income source from Fannie Mae, and it can be a useful tool to qualify the borrower both as a main stream of income or as supplemental
                  income to solve for minor DTI restructures. This is separate from the Fannie Mae guidelines surrounding employment-related assets and IRA distributions found in section B3-3.1-09.
                </p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>Assets as income involves reviewing the balance in the borrowers various asset accounts and using a calculation to determine a monthly income that can be used to qualify the loan.</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <table class="table-complex primary" style="text-align: center;">
          <thead>
            <tr class="primary-type">
              <th colspan="2">DRY FUNDING STATES: Funds are sent when the Wire Team receives a funding request from Title/Escrow<br />
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="data">
              <td><span style="text-align: center;">Alaska</span></td>
              <td>Nevada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>Arizona</td>
              <td>New Mexico (refinances)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>California</td>
              <td>Oregon</td>
              <td>The Further</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>Idaho</td>
              <td>Washington</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="data">
              <td>Hawaii</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="component content">
    <div class="component-content">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="component link">
    <div class="component-content">
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How do you use this regex?

Comment: I advise you this tool: [regexper](https://regexper.com/#%3C%28%3F!th%29%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3E%5B%5E%3C%5D*%28%5C%5Cbabc%5C%5Cb%29). I replaced the string with `abc`

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina https://regex101.com/ has much better interface with enough contrast so everyone can read

Comment: @Konrad I am using a .replace() method with the regex and replacing each instance of the matched word found with <span class=document-highlight> 'matchedWord' </span>

Comment: @Konrad Regexper is not for testing regex ma to visualize and debug them, I think it's much better but just my opinion :)

Comment: looks too greedy, maybe try replacing `'<(?!th)[^>]*>` with `'<(?!th)[^>]*?>`

Comment: @dandavis thanks for the comment! Tried that and gave me the same results I had before

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar I have included an executable version

Comment: Why are you using a regexp on the HTML when you can use DOM or jQuery methods to find the elements directly?

Comment: @Barmar there is no reason

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to try to use regular expressions to parse HTML. The browser has a built-in parser, use that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454